# Using document.saveAs(fileId) function

Tags: google-drive-realtime-api

Please share if anyone has a deep info of how to use this function and what fileId to input in realtime api document.saveAs(fileId) function.

i have provided the api documentation

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/realtime/reference/gapi.drive.realtime.Document.html#saveAs

Answer (score 0):

I think the link you've provided says what it does already.

> "Saves a copy of this document to a new file. After this function is
>   called, all changes to this document no longer affect the old document
>   and are instead saved to the new file. "

snippet:

```
var newDoc = gapi.drive.realtime.loadFromJson(jsonData);
newDoc.saveAs(fileId);
```

The *fileId* mentioned here is the id of the new document you wish your future changes to be copied to and reflect the incoming changes. Example:
If you don't have idea what *fileId* looks like, it's something like this.

If it's a docs file,

```
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Fh6s7an-7I6VuDBxZMcxcaL9cG1XplryHPOGnznWlns/edit
```

`1Fh6s7an-7I6VuDBxZMcxcaL9cG1XplryHPOGnznWlns` is the fileId.

If it's a sheets file,

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BD97LZlG5qxVHyvPvZ-i_mahh-yUPuFCG2ZW4yhN8vs/edit#gid=0
```

`1BD97LZlG5qxVHyvPvZ-i_mahh-yUPuFCG2ZW4yhN8vs` is the fileId.